# Вывести комментарии из темы в вк

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Здравствуйте,  подскажите как вывести обсуждения из вк с возможностью добавления отзывов?

Вот что получилось, все выводит кроме иконки пользователя.

```
$wall = file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/board.getComments?v=5.3&group_id=36679165&topic_id=34087057");

$wall = json_decode($wall);
$wall = $wall->response->items;

for ($i = 0; $i < count($wall); $i++) {
    echo "<p><b>".($i + 1)."</b>. <i>".$wall[$i]->text."</i><br /><img src=".$wall[$i]->photo."/><span>".date("Y-m-d H:i:s", $wall[$i]->date)."</span></p>"; // Выводим записи
}

echo $wall;
```

Comment: Уточните, что вы имеете ввиду под возможностью добавления отзывов?

Answer (score 0):

Нужно передавать в запросе параметр extended=1(https://vk.com/dev/board.getComments), тогда в массиве будет также возвращаться массив с информацией о пользователях, там будут и аватарки.

А вот добавление отзывов сделать не получится - публикация в темах доступна только клиентским приложениям, на сайтах такие методы никак не вызвать.